# plt.hist with density = True does not work

Tags: matplotlib, plot, histogram

From what I understand hist() is supposed to normalise the bars, unfortunately with the following code I do not get correct bar heights

```
data = np.loadtxt("../data/data_queue_R" + str(64) + "_" + str(1) + ".txt")
print(data)
hist = plt.hist(data, bins=40,density=True)
```

I get the following
[image]

Comment: Your bar heights seem to be perfectly fine.  With `density=True`, the total **area** of the bars should sum to `1`. As your x-axis is in the range of `0.001`, the y-axis needs to be in the range of `1000` for the product of x and y to be around 1.

Comment: In case you don't want density, Seaborn's `sns.histplot` has options to normalize as percentage or probability.